# AutoBogus configuration and Bogus Determinism

Tags: bogus

When using the AutoBogus builder configurations with either the Create or Generate methods, I can't seem to find the way I can provide the deterministic way to seed random. UseSeed is not available.

For example:

```
            var orderFaker = AutoFaker.Create(builder => builder.WithOverride(new OrderOverride()));


            orderFaker
            // .UseSeed(<int>) is not available on orderFaker
            .Generate(5);
```

Similarly,

```
            List<Order> sut = AutoFaker.Generate<Order>(5, 
                builder => builder.WithOverride(new OrderOverride())
            );
```

Am I missing something or is it just not available at this level?

---

As a workaround, my override class just has a static method for the Rules being applied, making applicable in the override as well as when instantiating `AutoFaker<Order>`.  This seems to be working, but just wondering if there's a better way...

```
            Faker<Order> orderFaker = new AutoFaker<Order>().Rules(
                OrderOverride.OrderGenerator);

            List<Order> actual = orderFaker
                // https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus/tree/cc2f894e46be08e3a1521f31b464017666f4f8c7#determinism
                // UseSeed at the faker level ensures consistent output
                .UseSeed(1338)
                .Generate(5)
                .ToList();
```

```
    public class OrderOverride : AutoGeneratorOverride
    {
        public override bool CanOverride(AutoGenerateContext context)
        {
            return context.GenerateType == typeof(Order);
        }

        public override void Generate(AutoGenerateOverrideContext context)
        {
            var o = context.Instance as Order;
            var f = context.Faker;

            OrderGenerator(f, o);
        }

        public static void OrderGenerator(Faker f, Order o)
        {
            o.LineItems = new AutoFaker<OrderLineItem>().GenerateBetween(2, 5);
            o.Notes = f.Lorem.Text();
        }

    }
```

Comment: As it turns out, the workaround is not working after all.  With my previous test, the `GenerateBetween(2, 5)` rule was being applied, but upon further inspection, the rule for `o.Notes = f.Lorem.Text()` is not being applied, nor is another attempt with `o.Notes = f.Lorem.Sentences()`.